# TTLauncherView remove the delete button

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, button, ttlauncherview

I am using TTLauncherView to build a view,but I don't want the delete button when the icon is wobbling,how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution just now,just change something in the `- (void)beginEditing` method:

```
- (void)beginEditing {
  _editing = YES;
  _scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES;

  UIView* prompt = [self viewWithTag:kPromptTag];
  [prompt removeFromSuperview];

  for (NSArray* buttonPage in _buttons) {
    for (TTLauncherButton* button in buttonPage) {
      button.editing = YES;
        button.closeButton.hidden = TRUE;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This bevaviour is toggled when tapping on an icon. If you do not want the wobbling at all just override the following method:

```
- (void)buttonTouchedDown:(TTLauncherButton*)button withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    /// Do something what should happen
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have found another one.